# error to integrate restful web service with spring and gdata api

Tags: java, spring, rest, gradle, gdata

Short version: A restful spring web service crashes when I include a dependency: com.google.gdata: core: 1.47.1

Long Version:

I was trying to make a restfull web service that consume certain information from a spreadsheet in google drive

this is my sequence of steps:

preparing classes that made the connection and the data obtained from drive (not web, only backend classes, unit and integration tests included): all ok

prepare a restfull web service with spring, basically download a spring tutorial (http://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/3/) and execute: all ok

then remove tutorial's business classes and include my components, change controllers to invoke my components, plus add gdata dependence in file graddle.build, try execute: houston we have a problem

It's strange, when start app context, log print something like this:

```
C:\Users\Grubhart\Documents\proyectos\error_Rest_Gdata\complete\src\main\java\com\yummynoodlebar\config\WebAppInitializer.java:39: error: can not find symbol 
     servletContext.setInitParameter ("defaultHtmlEscape", "true"); 
                   ^ 
     symbol: method setInitParameter (String, String) 
     location: Variable of type ServletContext ServletContext
```

but when the rest app is just downloaded (whitout my code, neither gdata dependency) it works, the only thing I did was add my code and the google api dependence, so I started to see what could cause the error

remove all my code (but leave the gdata jar) and... wait for it.. same error,

remove gdata dependency: it works

then add gdata dependency again and test: the same error again

So I think that by including the gdata jar does something that prevents start the entire app context

I created a repo on github to illustrate the error:

https://github.com/Grubhart/error_spring_restWS_gdata

the master branch has the code of a service that works without gdata dependence

gdata_error branch as you can imagine has added gdata dependency (only dependency, no extra code) in gradle.build file:

compile 'com.google.gdata: core: 1.47.1'

and presents the error

no need install anything (even gradle) only have jdk, download the code and run it as stated in the readme file to see errors

i do my homework, look in google, stackoverflow (great site!), spring forum but can't find nothing

if anyone has experience with this problem, or know where i can found more information would be great if you can share experiences or if you know where to look for more info about this error

Answer (score 1):

The original post doesn't contains:

```
yummynoodlebar\config\WebAppInitializer.java:39: error: cannot find symbol
    servletContext.setInitParameter("defaultHtmlEscape", "true");
```

`ServletContext` needs import `javax.servlet.*;` Maybe the error is for that.

Comment: thanks!! but the class com.yummynoodlebar.config.WebAppInitializer (https://github.com/Grubhart/error_spring_restWS_gdata/blob/master/complete/src/main/java/com/yummynoodlebar/config/WebAppInitializer.java) include the import :

import javax.servlet.FilterRegistration;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;

i think is related with dependency version conflicts as @jastonitas said this weekend i try. +1 for the early reply

Answer (score 1):

Since the spring context configuration in java classes for web applications works with Servlet 3.0 maybe you have overwritten troubles between some dependencies that comes with gdata which may do use of dependencies other than the servlet version you are using to deploy the application or which it was originally configured, I hope this helps you!.